# SQL query updating column in a table based on comparing two different pairs of value from different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have two tables: `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`

The query should compare one pair of values in **two colums** in one table and corresponding pair of values in **two rows** in another table.

I need to update whole column `RESULT` with values 1 OR 0 this way:

```
IF (PRICE_LEFT > PRICE_RIGHT AND COL_LEFT_RANK > COL_RIGHT_RANK)
OR (PRICE_LEFT < PRICE_RIGHT AND COL_LEFT_RANK < COL_RIGHT_RANK)
THEN RESULT = 1
ELSE RESULT = 0
```

I used imaginary COL_LEFT_RANK and COL_LEFT_RANK as columns with assigned values from RANK column corresponding to their values in COL_LEFT and COL_RIGHT

I am using SQL Server LocalDB database.

Here is the example of how it should work:

[image]

Here's DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (
    COL_LEFT varchar(255),
    COL_RIGHT varchar(255),
    PRICE_LEFT int,
    PRICE_RIGHT int
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE_2 (
    COL varchar(255),
    RANK int
);


INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'G', 22, 4);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('C', 'A', 15, 14);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'D', 5, 18);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('A', 'F', 2, 2);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('F', 'E', 4, 8);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('G', 'C', 16, 6);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('D', 'C', 22, 28);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('A', 'G', 14, 19);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('F', 'D', 3, 12);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'A', 11, 9);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('D', 'F', 8, 2);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (COL_LEFT, COL_RIGHT, PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT) VALUES ('B', 'F', 4, 1);

INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL, RANK) VALUES ('A', 5);
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL, RANK) VALUES ('B', 3);
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL, RANK) VALUES ('C', 1);
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL, RANK) VALUES ('D', 7);
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL, RANK) VALUES ('E', 6);
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL, RANK) VALUES ('F', 2);
INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (COL, RANK) VALUES ('G', 4);
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
select COL_LEFT,tb21.[RANK],COL_RIGHT,tb22.[RANK],PRICE_LEFT, PRICE_RIGHT, 
result = case 
            when (tb21.[RANK] > tb22.[RANK] and PRICE_LEFT > PRICE_RIGHT) or (tb21.[RANK] < tb22.[RANK] and PRICE_LEFT < PRICE_RIGHT)
            then 1
            else 0
        end
from table_1 tb1
left join table_2 tb21 on tb1.COL_LEFT = tb21.col
left join TABLE_2 tb22 on tb1.COL_RIGHT = tb22.col;
```

using update

```
update table_1
set table_1.result = case 
            when (tb21.[RANK] > tb22.[RANK] and PRICE_LEFT > PRICE_RIGHT) or (tb21.[RANK] < tb22.[RANK] and PRICE_LEFT < PRICE_RIGHT)
            then 1
            else 0
        end
from table_1 tb1
left join table_2 tb21 on tb1.COL_LEFT = tb21.col
left join TABLE_2 tb22 on tb1.COL_RIGHT = tb22.col;
```

Comment: Thank you. But are you sure it is updating the column RESULT? There's no "UPDATE" keyword.

Comment: Ok, it returns the column with values (they seem to be correct) but it does not actually update the column. It kinda crucial thing here.